# Setting up Musicbrainz prepared dataset in Neo4j fails

Tags: neo4j, musicbrainz

I've downloaded the Musicbrainz prepared dataset and tried to connect it to my server, but when I try to start the database up it fails stating "Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@629b10d1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: **'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version**, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state."

Since this isn't a database of mine, I don't know whether it was shut down properly or not.
I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 with Neo4j 2.1.4 and the allow_store_upgrade is set to true.

Comment: Usually that message indicates a problem upgrading an earlier version of a database.  Have you tried starting the DB cleanly with neo4j-shell?  Do you get the same thing?  Did you create this DB with an earlier version not in the 2.1 series?

Comment: For reference, please provide a link to the Musicbrainz dataset you are using so we can try to reproduce the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi FrobberOfBits,
you were right. I downloaded neo4j from the 2.0 series and it worked smoothly. Later on, I tried going back to my neo4j 2.1.4 server and it now works. I guess the database had to upgrade himself between the version series, so now everything is working. 
Thanks a lot.